# Ubuntu Failed to start RabbitMQ broker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq

Im having a hard time trying to install RabbitMQ . Ive tried debian through webmin, done a sudo apt-get, tried sudo wget url then sudo dpkg -i . All attempts have failed with an Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking into the server itself, providing a solution for your type of issue is extremely difficult, but since your objective is installing rabbitmq on server and if you're open to docker I suggest using the pre built docker that is provided by rabbitmq, which takes the implementation process a lot easier, faster, hassle free and makes restarts extremely easy.

First install docker in your server then do as the following link instructs.

https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/

If this does not suit you I suggest using the following link to uninstall everything rabbitmq related and go with a fresh installation

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/rabbitmq-server?action=remove